# Binding the Background color of an Item in the LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

In my **Windows Phone 8** application I am using a **LongListSelector** to display grouped data. I would like to **bind the background color of the item** in the ItemTemplate to the **SelectedItem** using a value converter.

However, I cannot figure out how to access the selected item in the value converter to return the correct background color. What is the correct way to setup the coloring of the selected item in a LongListSelector?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? 99 times out of 100 using a value converter isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to convert value in code end pass the converted value to XAML.

You can access selected item data object by yourLongListSelector.SelectedItem.DataContext

Comment: For me, the SelectedItem (which is assigned from e.AddedItems[0] in the SelectionChanged event) is of the application item type (Product in my case) so there is no DataContext available.